# how to count items of OneToMany element via Spring data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

i have a user Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
    ....
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_post",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")})
    private Set<PostEntity> posts;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_followers",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "follower_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<UserEntity> followers = new HashSet<>();
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_followings",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "following_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<UserEntity> followings = new HashSet<>();

}
```

now i want to count followers of a user.
i can get list of followers and use list.size() but this is not good . i just want count of them not whole objects .is this possible by a method in my UserRepostiory that extends JpaRepostiory or a native query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use JPQL syntax. In your `UserRepository` you can add count methods. Please try :

```
@Query("select count(p) from User u join u.posts p where u.id = ?1")
long countPosts(Long id);

@Query("select count(f) from User u join u.followers f where u.id = ?1")
long countFollowers(Long id);

@Query("select count(f) from User u join u.followings f where u.id = ?1")
long countFollowings(Long id);
```